# Resizing ext4 partition of a guest Ubuntu on vmdk on ESXi 6.0

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, virtual-machine, ext4, esxi

I have rather old ESXi 6.0 that hosts a vm with Ubuntu. I need to increase the disk for it.

I don't have `vmware-vdiskmanager` as advised in https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004047

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps that worked for me:

### On ESXi

Find vm id:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
```

And power off:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off 6
```

Resize the vmdk file *(specify `xxxxx.vdmk` instead of `xxxxx-flat.vmdk`)*:

```
vmkfstools -X 500G xxxxx.vmdk
```

Power on vm:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on 6
```

### On guest vm

Use `parted` and `resize2fs`:

```
$ sudo parted
GNU Parted 3.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 537GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  500GB   500GB   ext4

(parted)
(parted)
(parted) resizepart 2
Warning: Partition /dev/sda2 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? Yes
End?  [500GB]? 537GB
(parted) q
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem at /dev/sda2 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 59, new_desc_blocks = 63
The filesystem on /dev/sda2 is now 131071483 (4k) blocks long.
```